# Concurrency Issue not Recreatable through a JMeter Script

Tags: concurrency, jmeter, performance-testing

Development analysis had revealed that a certain issue had occurred due to two concurrent user requests being executed in the server. However, when the same was performed using a JMeter script with two threads(users), the issue did not get reproduced despite both threads being synchronized using a synchronization timer for the save method request and the listeners indicating that both response times of the threads were the same for that particular request.

What could be the potential cause of this observation? and could there be suggestions to improve the test to either disprove or prove this claim in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can come up with the following assumptions:

1. The analysis result is not correct
2. The analysis result is correct but the issue is intermittent or [Heizenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)-like
3. You're not sending "the same" request using JMeter, maybe the payload is incorrect or you miss a [header](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager). If it's possible to obtain a network footprint of the issue in form of i.e. [.pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) or [.har](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) file you could compare it with the network footprint produced by JMeter

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent user actions and simultaneous user actions and two different things. Please see the details in this [article](https://www.perfmatrix.com/concurrent-users-vs-simultaneous-users/).

Following diagrams taken from the [article](https://www.perfmatrix.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Simultaneous-Users.jpg) explain the difference.

[image]

[image]

JMeter will simulate the concurrent user actions by defaults. What you really need is to simulate simultaneous user actions. You can achieve this by adding a [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) to your test plan.

> The purpose of the SyncTimer is to block threads until X number of threads have been blocked, and then they are all released at once. A SyncTimer can thus create large instant loads at various points of the test plan.

Comment: Janesh I am aware of synchronization timers, thanks anyway :)